# Where is the iOS cache?

Tags: ios

As I understand iOS has some file cache.

As example, when application tries to load some framework (a.e. CoreAudio), it loads it from cache . As I understand on a device for this reason /System/Library/Frameworks/ doesn't contain any code (because iOS developer knew they it will be always available in the cache).

Is there a way to read this cache to see what is in it?

Usual disclaimer: I am aware of AppStore rules. I don't plan to release this application to AppStore. It's only for research purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armv6 (or 7).

Yes, there are tools with which you can extract the actual dylibs from it; for example [KennyTM's dyld_decache.](https://github.com/kennytm/Miscellaneous/blob/master/dyld_decache.cpp)